# Extremely high loss and low accuracy when training model despite the same code working 2 years ago

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new here but 3 days of sleepless nights have been enough to drive me desperately to ask for help here :( To keep things short, I have been working on training a dog breed classification model, specifically this one from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification).

I had a full complete old code from 2 years ago that achieved decent accuracies around 70-80%. The code is as below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#import the necessary libraries/modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2, ResNet50
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_df = pd.read_csv("./data/train_labels.csv", dtype=str)
validation_df = pd.read_csv("./data/validation_labels.csv", dtype=str)

#returns the number of unique classes we are dealing with
num_classes = train_df["breed"].nunique()

#image_size to be used
dimensions = 400
image_size = (dimensions, dimensions)

#rescale and preprocess image
train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input, rescale=1./255, horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, zoom_range=0.1, width_shift_range=0.05, height_shift_range=0.05)
validation_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

print("ImageDataGenerator Done.")

#train_generator for training data
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train_df,
directory="./data/train/images/",
x_col="id",
y_col="breed",
batch_size=16,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=image_size)

#validation_generator for validation data
validation_generator=validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=validation_df,
directory="./data/train/images/",
x_col="id",
y_col="breed",
batch_size=16,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=image_size)

print("Generators done.")

#using inceptionresnetv2 as base model
base_model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(dimensions, dimensions, 3))

#set last 160 layers of base_model to be trainable
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False

#create new model, add base_model and add final layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

#show summary of model
print(model.summary())

#compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(0.01), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#save model after every epoch
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./models/model-{epoch:02d}-{val_accuracy:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, verbose=1, save_freq="epoch")
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size
hist = model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
epochs=30, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)
```

However, I have stayed away from machine learning for a while now and only recently decided to give it a try again (so I just ran this code again for a start). To my surprise, running the same piece of code yielded accuracies of 1% and the loss was exploding as you can see below:

[Low Accuracy and Exploding Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39ujj.png)

Checking for deprecation issues yielded nothing and so I have decided to try running another code instead from this [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/jcesquiveld/transfer-learning-for-dog-breed-classification-ii/notebook).

Apart from the file paths, my code is exactly the same as in the tutorial and yet, the accuracies and losses are behaving in exactly the same manner. I have checked and the images are fine, detected and processed. I have ran this on google colab, on a macbook and on an ubuntu VPS and still the accuracies and losses behave the same. At this point I am at a complete loss as to what could be the reason for this observation. I understand the guide is 2 years old as well so I am inclined to think there are certain functions that are no longer applicable or being misused but I have checked line by line again and again to no fruition ;-;

If there is any kind soul out there that could advice on why I am experiencing this I would really greatly appreciate it ;-; Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please do include the code for it.

Comment: Apologies I neglected to share the old code I had. To clarify, I have tried both my old code and the one from the kaggle tutorial and am observing similar exploding losses and low accuracies. Thank you!

Comment: Looking through it I cannot find any issues but maybe due to `model.fit_generator()` being deprecated it could come from there, so try it with `model.fit()` instead. If that doesn't work then I would start looking at the data you used.

Comment: I have tried both with fit and fit_generator but the accuracy in the first epoch always hovers around 0.01. In fact, halfway through the first epoch it starts crawling downwards already :( Subsequent epochs always show no improvements and continues to trend downwards. All the images are jpg and downloaded from kaggle. I am just so confused because even with a "bad model" it can't be that terrible until it is 1%. What's more I tried 2 sets of codes that were working at least 2 years ago ;-;